# How to write regex expression to replace string in oracle, for eg like 1_10!55AC

Tags: .net, regex, oracle11g, regex-negation

i need to replace 1_10!A5 into 1_10!A6 for the occurrences of a string in a column using like operator, but it will replace **1_10!A5**5 into 1_10!A65 , Please someone help to replace the exact string

Comment: use word boundaries before and after to your pattern like `\bregex\b`

Comment: @AvinashRaj what is `\b` in regex ?

Comment: see http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html

Answer (score 0):

The generic regexp would be /1_10!A5([^0-9])/ to replace with 1_10!A6\1

In Oracle :

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(your_field, '1_10!A5([^0-9])', '1_10!A6\1')
```

1_10!A5 will become 1_10!A6

and 1_10!A55 will stay 1_10!A55

Comment: it doesn't replace actual fields too

Comment: I don't know the exact context of your code but REGEXP_REPLACE(your_field, '1_10!A5([^0-9])', '1_10!A6\1') should replace 1_10!A5[not a digit] with 1_10!A6[the "not a digit" character] in what is in "your_field"